# Вопросительный знак или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Порой в блогах или в аське (словом, в интернет-общении) встречается такая ситуация: ты хочешь кому-то что-то показать и говоришь: "Видел у меня это...", далее следует некий массив текста или картинка. Так вот, какой тут нужен знак: вопросительный или двоеточие? Вроде, по логике, нужно двоеточие, но как тогда обозначить вопрос? А, если поставить вопрос, то не совсем понятно, что — это.
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы поставила вопросительный знак. Поскольку из дальнейшего (кон)текста понятно, о чем *этом* идет речь.

Answer (score 3):

После слова ЭТО поставьте двоеточие, если далее идёт предложение-пояснение. После вопросительного по цели высказывания предложения ставится вопросительный знак.
Поставьте после слова ЭТО вопросительный знак, если далее (или ниже) помещаете картинку, и больше ничего в сообщении нет.
Если же после картинки текст продолжается, то после слова ЭТО  - двоеточие, вопросительный знак ставьте после картинки. Картинка становится как бы частью предыдущего предложения. После знака вопроса вы продолжаете набирать текст.